# JavaScript Imports

Tags: javascript

I am trying to call the function `popup` from within `index.html`. When I view this code below in the browser  I get this error `ReferenceError: popup is not defined`. The reason why I am trying to do this is to better organize my code when I have many functions, I thought it might be easier to import them all into one file and then import that file into my `index.html` file. I don't know if this is best practice or not, but I thought it would help.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.scss">
    <script type="module" src="main.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <script>popup("testing")</script>
</body>

</html>
```

**main.js**

```
import { popup } from './main/popup.js';
```

**popup.js**

```
export function popup(x) {
    alert(x);
}
```

Comment: `popup` isnt defined globally. Exports are only accessible where you import them. If you want it in global space you will have to set it in the `window` object. Wouldnt suggest it though since you might as well make a regular js file and include normally

Answer (score 0):

Your `main.js` runs in a module, not on the top level. If you want to be able to reference it outside, from a non-module script, either explicitly put it onto the `window` to make it global:

```
import { popup } from './main/popup.js';
window.popup = popup;
```

(though, that kind of defeats the purpose of using modules at all)

Or put the script that calls `popup` into a module as well (rather than in an inline script):

```
<body>
    <script type="module" src='bodyScript.js'></script>
</body>
```

```
// bodyScript.js
import { popup } from './main/popup.js';
popup("testing");
```